# Python - Organisation of 3 subplots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I try to generate 3 subplots for my figure. It seems work but it is not perfectly aligned. How to have the same width between the figure at the bottom et the figures at below?

```
plt.close()
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.plot(cycles,np.asarray(df_int),'wo',label='')
ax1.plot(cycles,np.asarray(df_proj),'k+',label='')
ax1.legend(loc=2)
#ax1.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
ax1.set_ylim(0.001,0.004)

ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
i2=ax2.imshow(c,cmap=plt.cm.hot, vmin=-5, vmax=5);#plt.colorbar();plt.clim(-5,5)
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,ticks=[-5,0,5],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)



ax3 = plt.subplot(224)
i3=ax3.imshow(residue_proj,cmap=plt.cm.hot, vmin=-5, vmax=5);#plt.colorbar();plt.clim(-5,5);
cb3=plt.colorbar(i3,ax=ax3,ticks=[-5,0,5],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)

plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=500,  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
#plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is probably a lot easier if you use `GridSpec`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Create 2x2 sub plots
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

pl.figure()
ax = pl.subplot(gs[0, 0]) # row 0, col 0
pl.plot([0,1])

ax = pl.subplot(gs[0, 1]) # row 0, col 1
pl.plot([0,1])

ax = pl.subplot(gs[1, :]) # row 1, span all columns
pl.plot([0,1])
```

See: http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

[image]

Comment: is it at all possible to get the third figure the same size as the other two and centered alone in the second row instead?

Comment: I'm sure that's possible, but not something I (or anyone) can easily answer here in a comment. So perhaps ask a question about this instead?

Comment: Has this been deprecated now?  I get `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Auto-removal of overlapping axes is deprecated since 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later; explicitly call ax.remove() as needed.`

Comment: Do you get that warning with this exact example? I just checked with `matplotlib 3.6.2`, but don't get any warnings...

Answer (score 13):

The same as the above answer can be done with a figure object like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Create 2x2 sub plots
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]) # row 0, col 0
ax1.plot([0,1])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1]) # row 0, col 1
ax2.plot([0,1])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :]) # row 1, span all columns
ax3.plot([0,1])
```