# Making an odd number of subplots in Python

Tags: python, plot

I'm very new to Python, and I want to plot 13 different figures all in one plot. To do this nicely, I would like to plot the first 12 figures in a 6x2 grid (this works just fine), and then plot the 13th figure below it; either the same size as the other figures and centered, or larger than the rest so that its width is equal to twice the width of the other figures and all the edges are aligned. What would be the best way to specify axes of this kind using `subplots`? (So far, I've just used `nrows=6, ncols=2`, but I think something like that won't work with an odd number of figures to plot.) The code I have so far for plotting the first 12 plots looks like this (with simple test data):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=2, figsize=(45,10))
for ax in axes.flat:
   ax.plot([1,2,3,4])
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.5)
```

How can I add a 13th figure below the others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Organisation of 3 subplots with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360568/python-organisation-of-3-subplots-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GridSpec (link to documentation)](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to generate flexible axes layout.

The following code creates the desired layout and puts all `Axes` objects in a list for easy access.

```
gs00 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(7, 2)

fig = plt.figure()
axs = []
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(2):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs00[i,j])
        axs.append(ax)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs00[6,:])
axs.append(ax)
```

[image]